# Get vector of Tuesdays, but if Tuesday falls on a holiday, then replace it with Wednesday in R

Tags: r, date, dayofweek

I would like to find all of the Tuesdays between two dates. But if the Tuesday falls on a user-defined list of holidays, then I would like Wednesday instead.

This code works in my tests, but it is pretty janky and I am afraid it will fail silently.

```
low.date <- "1996-01-01"
high.date <- "1997-01-01"
holidays = c("01-01", "07-04", "12-25")
tues <- seq(as.Date(low.date), as.Date(high.date), by = 1) 
tues <- subset(tues, format(tues, "%a") == "Tue")
tues <- ifelse(format(tues, "%m-%d") %in% holidays, tues + 1, tues)
tues <- as.Date(tues, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

Thanks! I see answers pointing to the `timeDate` package, but I only see methods for finding business days or holidays. Is there a cleaner/safer logic than what I'm using?

Comment: Only a minor comment but re-using the variable `tues` like that will make it harder to test.  If there were an error in the second assignment to `tues`, say, it will be overwritten twice more by the end so it will be hard to trace back.

Comment: @G -- Good call. Thanks. Sometimes I think I am conserving RAM, but that's ridiculous in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIXlt in the base package gives you access to `wday` as a number, which is a little safer since names of days change from system to system.

```
low.date <- "1996-01-01"
high.date <- "1997-01-01"
holidays <- c("01-01", "07-04", "12-25")

all.days <- seq(as.Date(low.date), as.Date(high.date), by = "day")

# Tuesday is Day 2 of the week
all.tues <- all.days[as.POSIXlt(all.days)$wday == 2]
tues.holidays <- format(all.tues, "%m-%d") %in% holidays
all.tues[tues.holidays] <- all.tues[tues.holidays] + 1
```

Comment: This seems worse than the poster's solution.

Comment: Cleaned it up a bit, but I don't think it can get much clearer. The code in the original question sequences out all the days, then reformats and string compares every day to see if it's a Tuesday, then reformats every one to see if it's a holiday, and reassigns every day with an ifelse whether it needed to change or not. Sorry, but this is better.

Comment: It needs to stick to using `"Date"` class as in the poster's solution. The introduction of calculations based on seconds is particularly undesirable.

Comment: @Jon -- The `+1` is the skill I needed! I knew there had to be a better way than an `ifelse` and a re-class. I am still learning to think the R way.

Comment: And I think I can avoid the `POSIX` class operation by using the `weekdays()` operator.

Answer (score 4):

It's difficult to modify the logic of your solution. But here is a different form  using `wday` function from `lubridate` package.

```
hol_tue <-  wday(tues) == 3L & format(tues, "%m-%d") %in% holidays
wday(tues)[hol_tue] <- 4
```

Slightly inconveniently in lubridate package day count starts from Sunday with Sunday being day 1 as opposed to POSIXlt where it's 0.

Comment: Why is starting on Sunday inconvienant? You have to start the week somewhere and most businesses I have worked for used timesheets that started the week with Sunday. The standard strftime function also counts Sunday as day 0.

Comment: @Sharpie, 0 is not 1 :) This was my point (updated). I don't mind starting with Sunday but call it 0. POSIXlt refers to Tuesdays as the second day. I don't know how it is in US but in Europe when you say second day of the week you  mean Tuesday.

Comment: @VistoshKa -- Thanks! This is the second time I've heard of `ludridate`, so I'll have to check it out.

Comment: We made Sunday 1 to be consistent with what most people expect: the first day of the month is 1, the first day of the year is 1, January is month one, the first year is 1, ...  I don't know who thinks this is a good idea: `as.POSIXlt(ymd(20080101))$year`

Comment: Another approach is `wday(tues, T) == "Tues"` which is easier to understand when you come back to the code

Comment: @hadley, sounds reasonable. Would be also nice if `wday(tues)<-"Wed"` and `...<-"Wednesday" worked. In my answer above the wday<- function and readability of the code are the main reasons to use lubridate.

Comment: Good idea - added to the to do list at https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues/issue/82.

Comment: Another way to write the code would be `wday(tues) <- wday(tues) + days(hol_tue)` based on conversion of FALSE to 0 and TRUE to 1.